# How to create debuginfo package?

Tags: packaging, debian, deb

I have created rpm packages for a software along with debuginfo. For Ubuntu/Debian , I have only the software packaged as .deb but don't know how to create debuginfo .deb package. Please let me know how to create them.

Comment: For users like me who have no clue what debuginfo is, see http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Debuginfo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Packages in the official archives have debug packages build for them automatically. They are stored in a different archive though. They will have the names `foo-dbgsym`  You can access them by putting the following in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com natty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com natty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com natty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com natty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

*(Replace natty with the release you are running.)*

Information on how these are generated can be found here:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AptElfDebugSymbols

---

If you'd like to provide debug packages for a package which you maintain outside of the official archives, that is possible as well. This [Debian wiki article](http://wiki.debian.org/DebugPackage) is the best place to start.

Briefly, you must first create the new package in `debian/control` by adding:

```
Package: foo-dbg
Architecture: any
Section: debug
Priority: extra
Depends:
    foo (= ${binary:Version}),
    ${misc:Depends}
Description: debugging symbols for foo
 foo is a library that lets you do stuff.
 .
 This package contains the debugging symbols for foo.
```

Then in `debian/rules`, use `dh_strip` to strip debugging symbols from binaries, but retain them for use in the debug packages.

```
override_dh_strip:
        dh_strip --dbg-package=foo-dbg
```

Comment: For ubuntu build chroots, installing pkg-create-dbgsym will cause packages built in that chroot to also output -dbgsym packages when stripped.  This works for pbuilder, sbuild, cowbuilder, etc. and is how the "automatic" -dbgsym packages are generated in Soyuz.